# How to run multiple config files through a script?

Tags: bash, scripting, configuration, variable

I have a bash script that I've written that takes variables from a config file. I pass them from the command line like this:

```
./my_script.sh ./config1.conf
```

As I've continued to make more configs that need to be run, I now have to run a lot of commands to get through all the configs. I'm wondering if there is a way to have the script run through all the configs like rsyslog does by numbering them 01-first_config.conf, 10-config_ten.conf, 20-config_twenty.conf, etc. I've tried the following but it only runs the first file:

```
./my_script.sh ./*.conf
```

I could also just put all the variables in one file with separate sections but I'm unsure how to do that since each section would essentially have a complete list of all variables required by the script. Don't know how to pass each section through the script after the previous section finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decide whether you want this handling within (like `rsyslog`) or outside the script. If you want

```
./my_script.sh ./*.conf
```

to work then you have to adapt the script so that it accepts several parameters. Something like

```
for config_file; do
    . "$config_file"
done
```

Or you hard-code or somehow pass a directory with these files:

```
for config_file in /path/to/configs/*.conf; do
    . "$config_file"
done
```

Comment: Works perfectly. That's exactly what I needed. Thank you. Just still trying to understand in your first example how bash knows that the config_file variable refers to $1, $2, $3, etc?

Answer (score 1):

What should happen when you do `./my_script.sh ./*.conf` is that the glob expands to `./my_script.sh ./a.conf ./b.conf ./etc...conf`.

If what you want to do is launching `./my_script.sh` for each file of your glob, the following can fit your case:

```
$ ls -1 ./*.conf | while read CONF; do ./my_script.sh "$CONF"; done
```

Explaination: `ls -1` is used to expand the glob, 1 file per line. `while read CONF` starts a loop for each line.

---

As an alternative, you can use `./my_script.sh ./*.conf` and, inside your script, use `$*`, which will contain the glob expanded, or `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ... which correspond to the individual positional arguments, separated by space.

Comment: Excellent. Will either of these options wait until the first .conf file finishes running before running the second, etc? Some of my later .conf files are dependent on the results of the earlier ones.

Comment: IMHO `for conf in *.conf; do ./my_script "$conf"; done` would be preferable

Comment: @tjohnson yes, sequential execution, nothing in parallel. You have to add an `&` to make it parallell: `./my_script.sh "$CONF" &;` the script is sent to background and the loop finishes instantly.